# Setting the reference for a related entity with Entity Framework and generic repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working on a project that is like a member logger web application. I am having trouble in designing some server functionality (using ASP.NET). We store information about each member, all actions they take, what classes they attend and so on. The code looks something like this:

```cs
public class Member 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MemberKnowledge> { get; set; } = new List<MemberKnowledge>();
    // The reason this is a list is because you can skip some knowledge steps
}

public enum Knowledge 
{
    Primary, Middle, High
}

public class MemberKnowledge 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Knowledge KnLevel { get; set; }
    public int Stage { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; } = new List<Member>();
}
```

Here we use an `enum` in order to send a string to front end and be able to order all members by their `KnowledgeLevel` (each knowledge can have up to 5 stages, so the calculation is `Knowledge` * 10 + `Stage`.

I have a generic repository and then I branch into a bit more specialised repository classes used for each type. My generic repo looks like this:

```cs
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> 
{
    DataContext ctx;
    protected DbSet<T> table;
   
    public Repository(DataContext _ctx)
    {
        ctx = _ctx;
        table = ctx.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<T> GetAll() { ... }

    public virtual T? GetById(Guid id) { ... }

    public virtual T? Create(T? obj) { ... }

    public virtual T? Update(Guid id, T? obj) { ... }

    public virtual bool Delete(Guid id) { ... }

    public void Save() 
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that my repositories are modeled to use only their `tables` and not the whole `context`. I was planning on using only a Controller for `Members` and not `MemberKnowledge` since it's directly connected to the `Member` class. `MemberKnowledge` has preset values in the table and I want to be able to reference those somehow (on the website, you should be able to select one of the enums values and then add a number from one to five in order to add the knowledge, which should then in the database say, "ayy, use the knowledge in row x" so that later I can group all the members with a certain knowledge type).

Do I need to make `ctx` `protected` as well, or is there some other way I can go about doing this.

I tried making the ctx protected and made it work, but I'd prefer not doing it that way if possible.

This is one of my first posts and I really hope I made my problem clear. Thanks in advance :D